# How do I link individual options in a drop-down menu to a shopping cart?

Tags: interactive, dynamic-content, online-store

I'm building an online store for my music.  However, I'm letting the customer decide how much he or she wants to pay.  So, I've created this mark-up

```
<table>
                <tr><!--Off The Grid-->
                    <td>Off The Grid</td>
                    <td>
                        <object width="200px" height="15px">
                            <param name="src" value="../audio/off_the_grid_michael_pitluk.mp3">
                            <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                            <param name="controller" value="true">
                            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
                            <embed src="../audio/off_the_grid_michael_pitluk.mp3" autostart="false" loop="false" width="75px" height="40px" controller="true" bgcolor="#ffffff"></embed>
                        </object>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Tweet.</li>
                            <li>FB share.</li>
                            <li>
                                <select name="Choose Your Price" id="product-dropdown">
                                    <option value="">Choose Your Price</option>
                                    <option value="">$0.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$1.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$5.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$10.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$20.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$50.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$100.00</option>
                                    <option value="">$1000.00 :P</option>
                                </select>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
</table>
```

What do I need to do, specifically, to link each of the options in the drop-down menu to some kind of shopping cart.  So, let's say a customer decides they want to pay $20.00, so they select $20.00.  Now what code do I need to learn and what should I do specifically so that after they select $20.00 and click the "buy" button I'm going to create, it will take them to a pay pall shopping cart.

In other words, how do I connect each option in the drop down menu to the buy button?  How would I go about writing the code to do this? What language do I need?

As a model, I'm trying to basically do what http://amandapalmer.net/producttypes/digital/ is doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the purpose of creating an online-store, which have the look&feel of http://amandapalmer.net/producttypes/digital/, you'll have to learn some PHP code http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp, MySQL ( if you're going to use a database where will be stored the information for products, which you'll pull out via PHP into the web-site ), JavaScript/jQuery - to make it looking more interactive. And you'll have to use html form element to pass the data from the select box into the shopping page.